# Error in filling static array dynamically in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have to use a static two-dimensional array and a dynamic matrix as a part of my college task. 
So, I've created them, and now trying to fill and then print them to a console, but getting "segmentation fault". That's how I'm trying to achieve it:

```
#include "arrayutils.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 5
#define COLUMNS 7

int main3() {
    /*init static array*/
    double twodimarray[ROWS][COLUMNS];

    /*init dynamic array*/
    double **matrix = (double**) malloc(sizeof(double*) * ROWS);
    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) *(matrix + i) = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * COLUMNS);

    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
        dfillarran(*(matrix + i), COLUMNS);
        dfillarran(twodimarray[i], COLUMNS);
    }

    puts("Dynamic matrix :");
    printmx(matrix, ROWS,COLUMNS);

    puts("Static array:");
    printmx(twodimarray, ROWS, COLUMNS);

    /*freeing mem*/
    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) free(*(matrix + i));
    free(matrix);
}
```

Error is definitely in function `printmx()`, but I can't understand why; It works for dynamic matrix, and fails only for static one, but static array name - is a pointer to array of pointers, where each one is pointing array of values, just like dynamic one!
There is code of my `printmx()` function from `arrayutils.h`:

```
/**Print Matrix*/
void printmx(double** mx, int rows, int col){
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            printf("%.lf ", *(*(mx + i)+j));
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Funcion that fills arrays with random values can be found [here](https://github.com/Maggistrator/c-is-life/blob/master/LabIV/arrayutils.c), in `arrayutils.c`, that I've created for all other tasks that use same functions like filling and printing arrays, but I don't think, that problem is there..
Probably, I'm wrong somewhere in theory, and still not getting the difference between static and dynamic matrix, please correct me :)

p.s.There is a screenshot of the error:
[image: there is an error]

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: @ScottHunter as I said above, there is "segmentation fault" (updated question with screenshot).

Comment: `a dynamic matrix`?  `double **matrix` does not refer to a matrix.  It refers to an array of pointers to multiple, separate one-dimensional arrays.  See [**Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).  Read that and you'll see why your code failed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks, I'll read it!

Comment: `*(*(mx + i)+j)` is better written as `mx[i][j]`. There is no other difference besides the former looking uglier, being harder to read and perceived less professional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `printmx` may not be called for the two objects of different types.

The array `twodimarray` is a two dimensional array that when is passed to the function has the type `double ( * )[COLUMNS]`.

While matrix is a pointer of the type `double **`.